# input type=file attached to an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, onclick

I have a menu like this:

```
<ul class="sub">
    <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Open</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Save</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I'd like to attach an onclick even to the Open li that would kick off a file open dialog, like `input type="file"` does.  I can handle attaching code to the li's onclick event, but I don't know what code to attach.

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a normal `input type="file"` to the page and style it to be hidden.  Something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="theFileInput" style="display:none;" />
```

(Only using in-line styling for this example, I recommend separating the style from the markup of course.)

Then you can initiate a click on it in response to a click event on the target element.  With jQuery (assuming you can set an `id` on the `li`, or otherwise uniquely identify it in the selector in some way) it would be something like:

```
$('#clickableLiElement').click(function() {
    $('#theFileInput').click();
});
```

The `input type="file"` is still there and can be interacted with just like any other form element.  It's just invisible to the user.  But this would launch the Open File dialog and set its value to the element normally, which can be included in the POST to the server normally.

Comment: does this work on ie? (IE won't allow javascript forced clicks on inputs)

Answer (score 2):

```
With JavaScript
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="images/*" name="images" id="images" onClick="showModal()" style="display:none"/>
<script>
    function showModal(){
        document.getElementById('images').click();
    }
</script>
<li onClick="showModal()"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above (David) works, but in your css file you need to do:

```
opacity: 0;
-moz-opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
```

The `display:none` solution is not working with Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Wrong. This will hide it in all browsers. Tested.